# Back button doesnt pause my app

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button, pause

I Have 2 activities in my app - Welcome, Login.
The app starts with the Welcome activity, then finishes it and starts the Login activity:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Welcome.this, Login.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

I've  also override the `onBackPressed` function:

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(a);
}
```

But when I try to click the back button on the Login activity (as shown 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwkn9.png)) nothing happens.

I want the app to close and return to the previous app when i click the back button.

Thanks Ahead,

Amit

Comment: `I want the app to pause when i click the back button.` add more details!, also have you override the `onBackPresssed` method?

Comment: Edited the question to explain it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow on the toolbar is not a "back button", but an "up button" and should, at least in theory, behave different from the device's back button ([see docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)).

If you want it to behave like a back button, you can manually wire it to do that:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

If you want your app to disappear to the background, there is **no need** for you to override `onBackPressed()` and manually launch in intent for the homescreen as you did, given there is no backstack of activities, i.e. no activity "behind" your `LoginActivity`.